# Change Cell Background Colour from predefined RGB Colour List each time Macro is run

Tags: excel, vba, variables, colors, rgb

I'm trying to create a Macro where a range of cells Background colour is changed to a colour in a list of predefined RGB colours. Each time the macro is run the Range of cells colour changes to the next colour in the list.

I have a Reference number in cell "A9" that sets the number in the list of colours (defined as colourSel), and a list of 5 RGB colours underneath it (A10:A14). When the Last colour has been selected, the colourSel Variable resets and the list begins form the start again. I can cycle through the colours fine but I'm unable to set the Colour Variable (colourSet) using Interior.Color

**A9** 3 *(ColourSel)*
**A10** RGB(131, 99, 172)
**A11** RGB(240, 92, 106)
**A12** RGB(13, 176, 219)
**A13** RGB(231, 167, 35)
**A14** RGB(244, 130, 33)

I'm getting the error *Type mismatch* which I assume is because colourSet is defined as *String*

```
Dim colourSel As Integer
Dim colourSet As String

Range("a9").Select
If ActiveCell.Value > 5 Then
    colourSel = 1
    GoTo resetcolour
    End If

colourSel = Range("a9").Value

resetcolour:

Range("a9").Offset(colourSel, 0).Select
colourSet = ActiveCell.Value

colourSel = colourSel + 1
    Range("a9").Value = colourSel

    Range("b2:c3").Interior.Color = colourSet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function within your VBA to perform the conversion ...

```
Public Function ConvertRGBStringToValues(strRGB As String)
    Dim arrRGB As Variant

    ' This is an example of what can be passed into this function ...
    ' strRGB = "RGB(11, 105, 11)"
    
    arrRGB = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(strRGB, "RGB", "", Compare:=vbTextCompare), ")", ""), "(", ""), ",")
    
    ConvertRGBStringToValues = RGB(arrRGB(0), arrRGB(1), arrRGB(2))
End Function
```

... so you would apply it like this ...

```
Range("b2:c3").Interior.Color = ConvertRGBStringToValues(colourSet)
```